# Need to call API rest with SSL two way (X509) using Spring and keystore with multi alias

Tags: java, spring, keystore, x509

I need to call an API rest with SSL two way (X509) using Spring.
My JKS file got multi alias (mandatory).

I begun with this code to create a rest template:

```
KeyStore clientTrustStore = getStore(trustStore, pwdTrustStore.toCharArray());
        KeyStore clientKeyStore = getStore(keyStore, pwdKeyStore.toCharArray());

        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
            .setKeyStoreType(JAVA_KEYSTORE)
//.setKeyManagerFactoryAlgorithm(...)
            .loadKeyMaterial(clientKeyStore, aliasPwd.toCharArray(), new KeyStrategy(alias))
            .loadTrustMaterial(clientTrustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient =      HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConFactory).build()) {

            restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
        }

        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
```

For those who know how it works, it use the SunX509KeyManagerImpl.class (JDK8) that parse the keystore with this algorithm

```
SunX509KeyManagerImpl(KeyStore ks, char[] password)
            throws KeyStoreException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        credentialsMap = new HashMap<String,X509Credentials>();
        serverAliasCache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
                            new HashMap<String,String[]>());
        if (ks == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
                                        aliases.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String alias = aliases.nextElement();
            if (!ks.isKeyEntry(alias)) {
                continue;
            }
            Key key = ks.getKey(alias, password);
            if (key instanceof PrivateKey == false) {
                continue;
            }
            Certificate[] certs = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
            if ((certs == null) || (certs.length == 0) ||
                    !(certs[0] instanceof X509Certificate)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (!(certs instanceof X509Certificate[])) {
                Certificate[] tmp = new X509Certificate[certs.length];
                System.arraycopy(certs, 0, tmp, 0, certs.length);
                certs = tmp;
            }

            X509Credentials cred = new X509Credentials((PrivateKey)key,
                (X509Certificate[])certs);
            credentialsMap.put(alias, cred);
            if (SSLLogger.isOn && SSLLogger.isOn("keymanager")) {
                SSLLogger.fine("found key for : " + alias, (Object[])certs);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see beside the for, it extract with a enum the list of aliases and do a getKey with the password and the first random alias of the list. It throw an exception when the duo alias/pwd is wrong
`java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key`

I don't understand why I can't filter the alias which is gonna be tested or maybe all the alias must have the same password ? :) . I saw I can use setKeyManagerFactoryAlgorithm to create a custom KeyManager (to not use de SunX509KeyManagerImpl) but I wonder if it's the real good solution to reach my target.

I don't wanna reinvent the wheel

Thank for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I appears I can extract form the keystore and create inmemory keystore with only one alias.

```
    private static KeyStore createUnaryKeyStore(String alias, String aliasPwd, KeyStore clientKeyStore) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException, IOException, CertificateException {
    Key key = clientKeyStore.getKey(alias, aliasPwd.toCharArray());
    Certificate[] certificateChain = clientKeyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);

    KeyStore tempUnaryKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance(JAVA_KEYSTORE);
    tempUnaryKeystore.load(null);
    tempUnaryKeystore.setKeyEntry (alias, key, aliasPwd.toCharArray(), certificateChain);
    return tempUnaryKeystore;
}
```

So I'll use it to call my rest API